# I can't use the file I saved in Directory.Documents with ionic in xcode widget

Tags: swift, xcode, ionic-framework, widget

In my Ionic project, I save a base64 file as png into Documents. I want to use this in a widget in Xcode but I can't find the file. What am I doing wrong?

```swift
let pathss = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathss)

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let imageName = "xxx.png"
let foofile = documentsPath + "/" + imageName
let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: foofile)

if fileExists {
    print("Already exists")
}


let fileName = "xxx.png"

if let documentsURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.yyy.xxx")?.appendingPathComponent(fileName) {
    if let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: documentsURL.path) {
        let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        
    } else {
        print("ERROR")
    }
} else {
    print("NOT FOUND")
}
let temporaryDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
/// create a temporary file for us to copy the video to.
let temporaryFileURL = temporaryDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent ?? "")

var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

let currentDate = Date()
for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
    let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, fileName: temporaryFileURL.absoluteString)
    entries.append(entry)
}


let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
completion(timeline)
```

I tried many things but couldn't get any results.

When adding a file, save the file:

```
file:///var ...../Application/....
```

The location it tries to pull while fetching a file is:

```
file:///var ...../PluginKitPlugin/....
```

Other parts are the same. Additionally, I added App Group, but it does not save the file there.

Comment: did you fixed it? I also encountered this problem and couldn't solve it. @Mikber

Comment: Unfortunataly no :/ @fbdev1907